# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Workflow Tutorial not Working

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to follow the tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509012.aspx

However, when I get to the line:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
{
    IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

    //Create an Organization Service
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

    //Retrieve the contact id
    Guid contactId = this.Contact.Get(executionContext).Id;
}
```

It is giving an error in C#.

> C# 'Program' does not contain a definition for 'Contact' and no extension method 'Contact' accepting a first argument of type 'Program' could be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

What is `this.Contact`?

Answer (score 3):

Contact is an in argument for the custom activity workflow

```
//Define the properties
[RequiredArgument]
[Input("Update Next Birthdate for")]
[ReferenceTarget("contact")]

public InArgument<EntityReference> Contact { get; set; }

protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
{
    IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

    //Create an Organization Service
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

    //Retrieve the contact id
    Guid contactId = this.Contact.Get(executionContext).Id;
}
```

When you invoke the custom, from a workflow or an action, you have to send the required input arguments, like Contact.

Comment: ok thanks. So how I do use it to reference my custom entity? New_MyEntity with a field new_entityID?


Where do I send the required inputs?

Comment: @Techcrium [ReferenceTarget("contact")] is the name of your entity, it would be [ReferenceTarget("new_myentity")]. You call a Custom Activity Workflow from a Workflow or an Action, so created one of these and call the custom sending the entity you need.